# Memory efficient way to make an object empty in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

Basically what I want to do is, to use single object everytime after make it empty when my purpose is served.
For array in javascript, I used to write `arr.length=0` to make any array empty, instead of pointing it to different memory location. is there any way through which I can empty an object in javascript ?
Scenario is:

```
var obj = {};
obj["name"]="Aman";
obj["country"]="India";
console.log(obj); // output is { name: 'Aman', country: 'India' }
```

Can I reused this **obj** object after removing its content ? if so how ?

Comment: JSON is a data format. You are talking about "an object", there's nothing JSON about it.

Comment: @JoeSimmons — That wouldn't empty any other references to the same object.

Comment: @Quentin Yes I agree that JSON is a data format, but what my purpose is to make it empty.

Comment: You'll have to use a `for..in` loop to erase the properties. You should also use `hasOwnProperty` to make sure you only delete its own properties.

Comment: I didn't understand.. what make others to down vote this question...x(

Comment: @Aman Kids. that's all. (IMH - very important question)

Comment: Remove the word *JSON* from your question and title. It has nothing to do with JavaScript objects.

Comment: What browser / javascript engine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way I can think of would be to loop over the object and delete each property in turn.

```
var obj = {};
obj["name"]="Aman";
obj["country"]="India";

for (var prop in obj) {
    // Possibly with a hasOwnProperty test, depending on how empty you want it to be
    delete obj[prop];
}

console.log(obj);
```

Obviously, if you aren't dealing with multiple references to the object, you can just overwrite it with a new one.

```
var obj = {};
obj["name"]="Aman";
obj["country"]="India";

obj = {};

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Be sure to use `hasOwnProperty` -- don't want to be deleting any custom prototype methods.

Comment: appreciated... Thanks :)

Comment: For how to do the first option in TypeScript, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/67323880/8772169

Comment: Please note that the two ways differ in one important point if you use them on a parameter within a function. Way 1 will modify the object also outside the function, way 2 will not do that.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (var member in myObject) {
    if ( myObject.hasOwnProperty(member) ) {
        delete myObject[member];
    }
}
```

Comment: Be sure to use `hasOwnProperty` -- don't want to be deleting any custom prototype methods.

Answer (score 0):

use ECMAScript 6 Map:

```
var obj = new Map();
obj.set("name", "Aman");
obj.set("country", "India");
obj.clear();
```

Comment: I am not sure... but is it supported in all browsers ?

Comment: @Aman, not yet, but i hope somebody will investigate why `Map` was added to the spec