# Type inference in for ... in loop

Tags: typescript, type-inference

TypeScript's inference is very good. However, this example does not work as expected and needs a `//@ts-ignore`.

```
for (const p in obj) {
    if (p !== 'staticCounter' && p !== 'staticProperty') {
        //@ts-ignore
        delete obj[p];
    }
}
```

Without ignore, I get the error

> const p: string Element implicitly has an 'any' type because
> expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Obj'.   No
> index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type
> 'Obj'.ts(7053)

and `obj` is of type

```
interface Obj {
    a?: string;
    o?: string;
    b?: string;
    ...
}
```

While the idea is easy to grasp, I think it will not be easy to implement into TypeScript. A "Can be a key for obj" type is not what the type system supports.

But can this be improved on my side? I don't like `//@ts-ignore`s.

I am *not* looking for other ways to achieve the same thing. I chose this way, because it proved faster than creating a new object and assigning it the two new properties.

Comment: What is the type of `obj`?

Comment: What error do you get in its current form?

Comment: I added error message and (partial) type definition.

Answer (score 1):

You can put a type annotation like this:

```
let p: keyof Obj
for (p in obj) {
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a well-known limitation of TypeScript. The most [recent issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43284) asking to narrow `string` type to `keyof` of the object being iterated is presently open and awaits more feedback. Should you want to see it implemented, please go there, put a "like" on the issue and optionally provide a comment explaining your use case.

In the meantime an alternative to declaring the variable outside the `for...in` loop is to type cast:

```ts
interface Obj {
    a?: string;
    o?: string;
    b?: string;
}

const obj : Obj = {
    a: "John",
    b: "Mary"
};

for(const p in obj) {
  delete obj[<keyof Obj>p];
}
```